# How to add text to the center of cluster in k-mean algorithm

Tags: matlab

I have used K-means to cluster my data, then I plot the result and put specific mark to mark the centers, but I am trying to add some text as note. How can we do that?

```
  plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'square','Color','k','MarkerSize', 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text(x, y, txt);` to add text to a specific point of a graph.

Have a look at [Add Text to Specific Points on Graph](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-text-to-specific-points-on-graph.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) and [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) for more information.

**Update 1**

If you want each centroid to have a specific text you will have to specify a cell array of length equal to the number of centroids (length of str = K):

```
str = {'text1','text2', 'text3'};
plot(C(:,1),C(:,2),'square','Color','k','MarkerSize', 20);
text(C(:,1),C(:,2),str);
```

Where in this example there are K=3 means.

**Update 2**

You can initiate the `str` array using a loop as follows:

```
X = cell(K,1);
for ii=1:numel(X)
    X{ii} = ii; % Or you can use any other information related to the coordinates.
end
```

Comment: txt1='1';                                                                                                                                txt(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),txt1);   but it does not work.

Comment: it's `text()` not `txt()`.

Comment: its work , but can not detect the correct centroids , i have txt1= '1', for cluster one and txt2='2' for cluster two :                                                               plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'square','Color','k','MarkerSize', 20);                   text(tmp_x(:,1),tmp_x(:,2),,txt1);

Comment: specify an cell array with string of equal length to the number of centroids, and then pass it to text. http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html. I have updated the answer.

Comment: its work , but i have limitation, which is if i increase number of  K which is C and str= 3 then it will not work , i tried put  loop but also does not work :(

Comment: What is the text you would like to display? You could initialize it using a loop like in the *update* above.